# How to use multiple tables in crystal reports?

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports

I have a dataset and within that dataset I have 2 dataTableAdapteres.

The first datatable uses this query -

```
select * from a_object
inner join l_pageobject
on o_objectID = PO_ObjectID
inner join a_page
on po_pageid = p_pageid
inner join l_pagepermission
on p_pageid = pp_pageid
inner join a_permission
on P_permissionID = pp_permissionID
where p_description = 'testing.asp'
order by P_Name
```

and the second datatable uses -

```
select * from l_pagelink
inner join l_pageobject
on po_pageid = pl_pageid
inner join a_object
on o_objectID = po_ObjectID
inner join a_page
on pl_pageID = p_pageid
where p_description = 'testing.asp'
order by O_Name
```

I want to use both tables in a crystal report but cant seem to get it working.

Below is the code in c# that I have so far which ends up as an empty report.

```
public void reportOutput(string nameOfFile)
{
    string file;
    file = nameOfFile + ".pdf";

    ReportDataSet1 ds = new ReportDataSet1();

    CrystalReport1 objRpt = new CrystalReport1();
    objRpt.SetDataSource(ds);
    objRpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, file);
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where on earth your data set data is getting filled up??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to populate the DataSet instance through **Fill** method of tableAdapter.